# Shoot more than one bullet in this 1D C++ game

Tags: c++, loops, winapi

First of all, let me show you my code (assume it's in the main function):

```
#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

bool exit = false;

int g_x = 33;
int g_brx = 40;
int g_blx[5];

CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
int columns, rows;

GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
const int WIDTH = columns;//info->dwSize.X;


do {
    //Render
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        if (i == g_x) printf("x");
        else if (i == g_blx[0]) printf("<");
        else if (i == g_blx[1]) printf("<");
        else if (i == g_blx[2]) printf("<");
        else if (i == g_blx[3]) printf("<");
        else if (i == g_blx[4]) printf("<");

        else if (i == g_brx) printf(">");
        else printf("-");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //Process input
        if (_kbhit()) {
            char ch = _getch();
            switch (ch) {
            case 'h': if (g_x > 0) g_x--; break;
            case 'l': if (g_x < WIDTH - 1) g_x++; break;
            case 'j': if (g_blx[i] < 0) g_blx[i] = g_x - 1; break;
            case 'k': if (g_brx < 0) g_brx = g_x + 1; break;
            case 27: exit = true; break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Move bullets
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (g_blx[i] >= 0) g_blx[i]--;
    if (g_brx >= 0) g_brx++;
    if (g_brx >= WIDTH) g_brx = -1;

    Sleep(50);
} while (!exit);
}
```

This code prints in every iteration a line of `WIDTH` size, which can be either "x" (the player), "<" (bullets shot to the left side), ">" (bullets shot to the right side) or "-" (which is the symbol used when there is nothing of the previous things to print).

Then, it process the players input and discriminates whether the player has moved or a bullet has been shot. Then, it just moves the bullets. (I don't know if I have explained myself correctly because English is not my first language. Either way, I invite you to run it to see how it works).

What I'm trying to do (without success) is to shoot more than 1 bullet for each side, though I'm trying first with just one side, up to 5 bullets. But I can't seem to solve it. I've tried using arrays for `g_blx` and `g_brx` (bullet variables) and then looping over them but it just won't get my input correctly and therefore won't print 1 bullet after a keypress.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please make it [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by adding the parts missing for us _to run it to see how it works_.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't asked that much in StackOverflow :( But with the code I posted you can reproduce the problem I'm talking about @TedLyngmo

Comment: @Envy Just edit the question so it's possible to compile it for us too.

Comment: Oh, now I understand @drescherjm I edited the code with the things I tried without success so you can see it.

Comment: Yes I've just edited right now @TedLyngmo Thank you all for your interest

Comment: Thanks It's better. Can you add a minimal `int main()` with any includes necessary so that someone can just copy and paste to their compiler to test..

Comment: Okay, done. I've added the includes and the main function. Thank you @drescherjm :D

Comment: I will try to debug this later (a few hours sorry I have to go out soon) if no one answers.

Comment: Your keyboard loop is inside an `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {`, i.e. it won't move bullets until you've made five keyboard inputs, one per each `g_blx`. Is that what you meant? I'd guess instead you want to run the loop once, and if the user presses `j` then loop through g_blx to find one that isn't in flight and set that going.

Comment: `if (g_blx >= 0) g_blx[i]--;` needs to be `if (g_blx[i] >= 0) g_blx[i]--;` a similar change needs to happen in the following few if () statements in the move bullets.

Comment: The display loop: you should also use a loop to detect any `<` bullets rather than test each element of the array individually. e.g. start with `char c = '-';` (the default) and then run through a set of tests that might change `c`, and then `printf(c)` (or even `putc(c)`) at the end. i.e. `for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) { if (i == g_blx[j]) { c = '<'; break; } }`. Up to you how you arrange the logic where there's both a bullet and a character in the same square.

Comment: @Envy as side note, try writing in C++ instead of C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a standard C++ container, like `std::vector`, to keep track of your bullets and also create a `Bullet` class to store each bullet's properties, like its position, direction and how it should be painted (currently only `<` or `>`). Here's an example made with VS2017 with comments in the code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

// a class describing a bullet
class Bullet {
    int speed; // direction
    int x;     // current position
    char ch;   // its visual representation
public:
    // constructor
    Bullet(int X, int Speed, int Ch) : speed(Speed), x(X), ch(Ch) {}
    // accessors
    inline int getX() const { return x; }
    inline char getChar() const { return ch; }
    // telling the bullet to do its thing
    void Move() { x += speed; }
};

// a class to maintain a number of bullets
class BulletList {
    static constexpr size_t MaxNumberOfBullets = 5;
    std::vector<Bullet> bullets; // storage for Bullet objects
    int max_x; // the last column
public:
    // constructor
    BulletList(int columns) : bullets(), max_x(columns-1) {
        bullets.reserve(MaxNumberOfBullets);
    }
    // method to add a bullet (if we haven't reached MaxNumberOfBullets yet)
    bool AddBullet(int x, int speed, char ch) {
        if (bullets.size() < MaxNumberOfBullets) {
            bullets.emplace_back(x, speed, ch);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // method to tell all bullets to move and remove
    // those who's left the playing ground
    void MoveBullets() {
        for (auto it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end();) {
            it->Move();
            if (it->getX() < 0 || it->getX() > max_x) it = bullets.erase(it);
            else ++it;
        }
    }
    // method to "paint" all bullets in a prepared graphical buffer
    void addBulletsToGraph(std::string& line) const {
        for (const auto&b : bullets) 
            line[b.getX()] = b.getChar();
    }
};

int main() {
    bool exit = false;

    int g_x = 33;

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    int columns, rows;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
    const int WIDTH = columns;//info->dwSize.X;
    BulletList bl(columns);

    do {
        //Render
        std::string graph(columns, '-');  // create a line of '-'
        bl.addBulletsToGraph(graph);      // paint the bullets
        graph[g_x] = 'x';                 // paint the player
        std::cout << graph << std::flush; // print the whole graph at once

        //Process input
        if (_kbhit()) {
            char ch = _getch();
            switch (ch) {
            case 'h': if (g_x > 0) g_x--; break;
            case 'l': if (g_x < WIDTH - 1) g_x++; break;
            case 'j': bl.AddBullet(g_x, 1, '>'); break;
            case 'k': bl.AddBullet(g_x, -1, '<'); break;
            case 27: exit = true; break;
            }
        }

        //Move bullets
        bl.MoveBullets();

        Sleep(50);
    } while (!exit);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!! I like your design very much becase I was thinking about something similar but didn't know how to code it properly. Again, thank you very much Ted!

Comment: @Envy Great! On the topic of ASCII grapical games, take a look at ANSI graphical codes. You'll be able to "paint" what you need instead of repainting the whole scene.

Answer (score -4):

The first mistake you're making here is trying to divide between leftwards bullets and rightwards bullets. There should just be one array of bullets, where the entries is the position of the bullet, and then you use the position of them to determine whether they go right or left. This is easy, since you've already defined two keys, one for shooting left and one for shooting right. The "tricky" part is handling what happens when a bullet leaves the world: I made the design decision to just have them vanish entirely, meaning there is one less bullet every time one leaves the screen. The way I've implemented this is by iterating through every bullet and "pulling them back", i.e the next overwrites the current.

The second mistake is the rendering foundation you're using. Iterating over a for-loop until you essentially stumble into the thing you want to draw is not very sustainable. To remedy this, I've introduced a char array where we store all the things we want to draw (the player, the bullets, and '-'), and then rendering is a matter of only a single printf.

I've also taken the liberty of making the game proceed only on input, as that is less confusing to me. Also changed the keys to asdf as that is more ergonomic to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {

    bool exit = false;

    int PlayerPosition   = 33;
    const int MaxBullets = 50;
    int Bullets[MaxBullets] = {};
    int CurrentBullets = 0;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    int columns, rows;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    rows    = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
    const int WIDTH = columns;//info->dwSize.X;

    char* RenderLine = (char*) HeapAlloc(
        GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY | HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, columns + 1
    );
    // Initial render
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        RenderLine[i] = '-';
    }
    RenderLine[PlayerPosition] = 'x';
    printf(RenderLine);
    do {
        //Process input
        char ch = getch();
        if (ch) {
            switch (ch) {
                case 'a': {
                    if (PlayerPosition > 0) {
                        RenderLine[PlayerPosition]   = '-';
                        RenderLine[--PlayerPosition] = 'x';
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'f': {
                    if (PlayerPosition < WIDTH - 1) {
                         RenderLine[PlayerPosition]   = '-';
                         RenderLine[++PlayerPosition] = 'x';
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'd': {
                    if (CurrentBullets < MaxBullets) {
                        RenderLine[PlayerPosition + 1] = '>';
                        Bullets[CurrentBullets++] = PlayerPosition + 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 's': {
                    if (CurrentBullets < MaxBullets) {
                        RenderLine[PlayerPosition - 1] = '<';
                        Bullets[CurrentBullets++] = PlayerPosition - 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 27: exit = true; break; // press escape
            }

            //Render
            printf(RenderLine);
            //Move bullets
            for (int i = 0; i < CurrentBullets; i++) {
                if (Bullets[i] > PlayerPosition) { // move right
                    RenderLine[Bullets[i]]   = '-';
                    if (Bullets[i] == (WIDTH - 1)) { // a bullet has left the screen on the right
                        Bullets[i] = Bullets[--CurrentBullets];
                    } else {
                        RenderLine[++Bullets[i]] = '>';
                    }
                } else if (Bullets[i] < PlayerPosition) { // move right
                    RenderLine[Bullets[i]]   = '-';
                    if (Bullets[i] == 0) { // a bullet has left the screen on the left
                        Bullets[i] = Bullets[--CurrentBullets];
                    } else {
                        RenderLine[--Bullets[i]] = '<';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (!exit);
}
```

Comment: ... what's wrong with `std::vector` that you'd roll out such a thing instead??

Comment: Everything. But really, OP seemed to have more of a C style anyway, and I prefer that to C++.

Comment: Please note that to remove a bullet, since they aren't "sorted", you could swap that with the last one and decrease the bullets count.

Comment: Implemented Bob's suggestion.